# Probability tree - is it right?

Tags: probability

Let's start with the question/scenario given. My attempt is at the bottom as an image. Have I done something wrong?

A survey sample with results that
30% of respondents were couples without children (A), 
42.6% were couples with children (B), 8.4% were solo parents(C), and “others” not in family are 19% (D).

They were asked whether or not they had stored emergency water. These are the percentages that had stored emergency water:

- A: 46%
- B: 40.4%
- C: 33.7%
- D: 36.2%

Questions:

a)  Draw a probability tree representing this scenario.

b)  What is the probability that a randomly selected respondent stored emergency water?

c)  If a randomly selected respondent had NOT stored emergency water, what is the probability they were a couple without children (A)?

d)  If randomly selected respondent had NOT stored emergency water, what is the probability they were either a couple with children (B) or a solo parent (C)?

[My attempt for all questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHyDs.png)